Varios return en C++
quería saber si era bueno poner varias sentencias "return 0" en el siguiente programita, lo he probado y funciona bien:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num_mes;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingrese el numero 
del mes del que quiera saber 
cuantos dias tiene en este año 
2.024 y a continuacion pulse 
'INTRO':\n";
    cin >> num_mes;

    if (num_mes == 1)
    {
       cout << "Enero tiene 31 
dias.\n";
    return 0;
    }
   
 // Hay más "if" del 2 al 11 todos ellos con su "return 0" pero he acortado el programita para que el sistema me permitiese publicarlo.
  

   
    if (num_mes == 12)
       cout << "Diciembre tiene 
31 dias.\n";
   
    return 0;
}

Es lo correcto o hay otra sentencia más adecuada que se pueda repetir tantas veces como se repite "return 0" en el programita? Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar con esta duda. Gracias.

El código repetitivo te indica que hay una forma más simple de codificar lo mismo. Por ejemplo, puedes poner nombres de meses en una arreglo, los días en otro y luego haces un solo "cout".

Muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que aún no he estudiado los arreglos y no sé cómo se utilizan.

Bueno, si siempre vas a hacer return 0, puedes eliminarlos y dejar un puro return 0 al final.

Además de lo que ya ha comentado @CandidMoe, hay casos en los que es preferible un único punto de salida de la función, esto es especialmente cierto para SW de misión critica. Por ejemplo, las recomendaciones MISRA incluyen esa regla

y si usas la estructure if-else ?? .. para que asegures un punto de salida en main.. tambien puedes optar por otro camino usando switch-case  .. para tener mas limpio el codigo y no te enrredes de tantos IF

mira usando if-else
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num_mes;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingrese el numero del mes del que quiera saber cuantos dias tiene en este año 2.024 y a continuacion pulse 'INTRO':\n";
    cin >> num_mes;

    if (num_mes == 1) {
        cout << "31 para enero\n";
    } else if (num_mes == 2) {
        cout << "29 para febrero.\n"; // porque 2024 es bisiesto
    } 
    // aqui: else if para los demas meses
    else if (num_mes == 12) {
        cout << "31 para dic.\n";
    } else {
        cout << "aqui el mes que no vale.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

y para switch-case seria asi:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num_mes;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingrese el numero del mes del que quiera saber cuantos dias tiene en este año 2.024 y a continuacion pulse 'INTRO':\n";
    cin >> num_mes;

    switch(num_mes) {
        case 1:
            cout << "31 ene.\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "29 feb.\n"; // 2024 bisiesto
            break;
        // aca agregas mas meses
        case 12:
            cout << "31 dic.\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "mes que no vale.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

cual te parece mas pulido? .. aqui te libras de todos los if cualquiera de los 2 deberia de funcionar

Muchas gracias, los dos funcionan muy bien, pero si tuviera que elegir me quedaría con el de switch-case.

Lo óptimo sería reducir la cantidad de código sin sacrificar legibilidad. La solución que plantea Candid Moe es buena, usa arreglos.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int num_mes;
const int diasMeses[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
const string nombresMeses[12] = { "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" } ;

int main()
{
    cout << "Ingrese el numero del mes del que quiera saber cuantos dias tiene en este año 2.024 y a continuacion pulse INTRO':\n";
    cin >> num_mes;

    cout << nombresMeses[num_mes - 1] << " tiene " << diasMeses[num_mes - 1] << " dias\n";
}

Mira que simple queda. Es cierto que faltan verificaciones, como que num_mes esté entre 1 y 12. También se podría dedicar una función para calcular el número de días por cada mes teniendo en cuenta el año, en especial por febrero.
Como curiosidad, utilizar varios ifs o un switch puede que resulte en un código fuente más extenso. Sin embargo, el compilador es inteligente y para optimizarlo crea una tabla, justo como si fuera un arreglo. Por eso en el desensamblado encuentras cosas como esta:
.LC0:
        .long   31
        .long   28
        .long   31
        .long   30
.LC1:
        .long   31
        .long   30
        .long   31
        .long   31
.LC2:
        .long   30
        .long   31
        .long   30
        .long   31

Así que no debería haber grandes diferencias de rendimiento entre las 3 opciones.

Muchas gracias Mateo, aún no había estudiado los arreglos y veo qué son muy útiles.
